# How to generate a tex document from the shell after installing MacTex?

Tags: mac, mactex

I am a new MacOS user, and have downloaded and installed MacTex on my machine.
How do I use it to convert .tex files to a pdf? I know in Windows I could use pdflatex and MikTex right after installation.

I want to go to my terminal and simply enter:
`pdflatex file.tex` and get the output I expect, like I did in Windows.

When I run `pdflatex file.tex` when I am in the directory with `file.tex` in my bash shell, I get `-bash: pdflatex: command not found`. How do I compile latex documents on the Mac?

Any advice you have would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to open a command window and navigate to the directory that contains `file.tex`?

Comment: yes I can do that @Mico

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that you've opened a [terminal window](https://macpaw.com/how-to/use-terminal-on-mac) and navigated (say, via suitable `cd` statements) to the directory that contains `file.tex`. To make pdflatex compile this document, you just need to type

```
pdflatex file
```

at the prompt.

---

In the following screenshot, I first ran `cat file.tex` to show its contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

I then ran `pdflatex file`; happily, no warning or error messages were issued. Finally, I ran `ls -l file.*` to show that in addition to the .tex file, there are three other files in the directory: `file.aux`, `file.log`, and -- probably most importantly to you -- `file.pdf`.

[image]

Comment: Incidentally, this answer assumes that you downloaded and installed MacTeX from its main repository at http://tug.org/mactex/. If you used some other installation method -- say, `homebrew` -- instead, you may have to adjust the `PATH` and other environment variables by hand.